# Group scheme representation from action of a group scheme on a variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, etale-cohomology, group-schemes, flat-cohomology

Let f be some homogenous polynomial of d.

Let $X = \operatorname{Proj} (k[x,y,z]/(f))$
where $k$ is algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$.

Now $G$ is a group scheme acting on $X$.

Is there some natural way to see $H^1_{fl}(X, \alpha_p)$ as a group scheme representation of $G$. Or in other words, is there some "natural" natural transformation $\phi:G(R) \rightarrow Aut_R(H^1_{fl}(X, \alpha_p) \otimes_k R)$ (Here $R$ is a $k$-algebra)?